# A rain-storm being gentle?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

From *Where I Lived, and What I Lived For* by *Henry David Thoreau*:

> This small lake was of most value as a neighbor in the intervals of a **gentle rain-storm** in August, when, both air and water being perfectly still, but the sky overcast, mid-afternoon had all the serenity of evening, and the wood thrush sang around, and was heard from shore to shore.

A gentle rain storm seems odd to me, isn't it to be at least at some degree of furious to be qualified as a *storm*? How can *gentle* be the adjective of a storm?

Comment: Your question makes me think what is more odd between *ruthlessly nice* and *gentle rainstorm*. Perhaps they'd be equally odd when we analyzed them. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A **gentle rain storm** can happen and it depends on the geography of the area and atmospheric conditions.  Thoreau is referring more to the downpour of water than the wind and thunder that can accompany storms.

The type of rain Thoreau is writing about also occurs in more southern climates on a regular basis during the **summer months** when there can be a **sudden downpour** for a few minutes to release moisture from the air on a daily basis.  This **type of rain** also occurs in the Boston area (Walden) during **hot summers** and are caused by ***nimbus*** clouds.  It is usually referred to simply as a **downpour** as distinct from **rain** or **raining**.

**Thunderstorms** with their great winds are caused by ***cumulonumbus*** clouds and require flat terrain to reach their full potential, for example in the Midwest of the US.  Because of rolling terrain, ***cumulonimbus*** clouds form less regularly in the northeastern US.